# Issue in calling Rest API from Android device

Tags: android, rest, cordova, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to call a REST API from Ionic code. The REST API is also developed in my local system. The IP address of my Windows system is say abc.def.gh.i. The `GET` request API has this URL: http://abc.def.gh.i:8088/check-price/code-001

**Problem**

I am able call the REST API when I build/run the app using command `ionic lab` (as this opens up the app on browser). This also works when Ionic code runs on an emulator using the command `ionic cordova run android --e78ab88d`, as this opens the emulator in same system.

This *fails* when I run the code on actual Android device by using command `ionic cordova run android --device`.

Any idea what the issue is?

Here is the provider class that is invoked when an `item` is passed from the text input:

```
@Injectable()
export class ServiceProvider {
   private urlGetStudentTest: string  = "http://abc.def.gh.i:8088/check-price";
    callCheckPrice(item) {
    console.log("------*****-----" + this.urlcheckprice + '/' + item);
    console.log("-----------" + item);
    return this.http.get(this.urlcheckprice + '/' + item)      .map(res => res.json())
}
}
```

I can see the two console outputs, after this application stops.

Comment: can you post what is error shown in console ?

Comment: Tried 2 commands mentioned in below points, nothing helped.

Comment: 1) ionic cordova run android --device : In this case i dont get any error on console or app, app launches correctly but the call to REST API does not work. Everything else in the app is working which does not call the API. API call event takes place when a button is clicked to check the price of an item.

Comment: 2) ionic cordova run android -lc --device : In this case i was asked to select one of the IP out 4 IP, that comes on the console. If i select any of the ip the error _**[Application Error: This connection to the server was unsuccessfull. (http://abc.def.gh.i:8100)]**_ comes on mobile app when it is launched on the andriod device. No console error in this case.

Comment: I am to solve this problem. The issue was in the way connection between mobile and computer was established. Thanks.